# How to cancel forwarding to Firefox any URL inserted into address bar of Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, internet

Internet Explorer opens any URL in Firefox, even I put the URL in address path bar. How to cancel this behaviors?

Comment: Link to screenshot of where you're putting in this URL, it might be Windows Explorer.

Comment: Cannot put image link because I'm a new user. I'm talking about Internet Explorer. I'm putting URL www.yahoo.com [Enter] => and Yahoo is opening in Firefox but not in IE.

Comment: You can add the link to the screenshot in the comments and someone will edit it in for you.

Answer (score 0):

Is Firefox set to be your default browser? If so, you can change this behaviour by setting Internet Explorer to be your default browser.

When you start Internet Explorer, if it isn't currently the default browser, it usually asks you if it can set Internet Explorer to be the default. If you have already answered "No" to this question and have checked the "Do not ask me this question again" box, there is a setting somewhere in the Options that will let you change your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Go to :

> Control Panel > Add/Remove programs >
>   set program access defaults

Here you can force the the default browser.